# c++ compile time constructed binary search tree

Tags: c++, c++11, binary-search-tree, template-meta-programming

I want to be able to say `trim<' ', '\t', '\n'>(str)`, have it use `is_ws<' ', '\t', '\n'>(ch)` underneath as a predicate. And I want the predicate to do O(log(N)) comparisons for each `ch`. Not compiling(ambiguous signature) O(N) fragment to demonstrate the idea:

```
template <char W1, char...Wn> bool is_ws(char ch) {
    return is_ws<W1>(ch) || is_ws<Wn...>(ch);
}

template <char W> bool is_ws(char ch) {
    return W == ch;
}
```

How would one do that?

Answer (score 2):

I did the exact same thing, except I cheated and used a bitfield ( 32 bits ), but I did do compile time assembly of the bitfield from template arguments:

```
template <char...> struct CtrlVec ;
template <char c> struct CtrlVec<c>
    { static_assert( ( c < 0x20 ), "Only for control characters" ) ;  enum { mask = ( 1 << c ) } ; } ;
template <char c, char... cs> struct CtrlVec<c, cs...>
    { static_assert( ( c < 0x20 ), "Only for control characters" ) ;  enum { mask = ( 1 << c) | CtrlVec<cs...>::mask } ; } ;
```

If you were dead set on searching, I would create a sorted array of char `"\t\n "` and use `std::lower_bound` to search it.  I would also do a `static_assert` on the elements of the array to confirm its proper construction.

Comment: is `std::is_sorted()` a constexpr?